# Retrieving database results in python

Tags: python, html, sql, loops

I'm trying to display a query result in a webpage using html page. I'm able to display only the first row in the column but i need to display all rows.please suggest :

```
def formval():
# --connection syntax here--
cursor = connection.cursor()
if request.method == 'POST':
    x = request.form['weekno']
    cursor.execute("SELECT Document FROM Backlog where custno=?",x)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return render_template('home.html',weekno=result)

home.html 
{% for docno in weekno %}
  <p>{{ docno }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
```

The above is the piece of code am using in html page to capture database results.

Thanks!

Comment: You sure that query returns more than one result?

Comment: Hi John! Yes i checked the output of the query in cmd shell and i can see all the results but on webpage i can't.